# Many to One relationship?

Tags: php, mysql, yii, one-to-many

The following MySQL code...

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
    id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    departmentId TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
        COMMENT "CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (departmentId) REFERENCES Department(id)",
    firstName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    lastName VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    ext SMALLINT UNSIGNED NULL,
    hireDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    leaveDate DATETIME NULL,
    INDEX name (lastName, firstName),
    INDEX (departmentId)
)

CREATE TABLE Department (
    id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    name VARCHAR(40),
    UNIQUE (name)
)
```

... defines a many to one relationship between an employee and a department. In other words, an employee can only be in one department, but a department can have many employees. But can someone explain this in more detail? How does the above code tell me that?

Comment: FYI -  You probably shouldn't use tinyint for departmentId, you'll run in to trouble. Just use Int.

Comment: There is no relationship defined between these tables. Read about the syntax of the [`CREATE TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) statement.

Comment: @axiac You are right in principle, but `comment` is read by the yii framework and used to automatically define relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sometimes easy to discern the relationship between two (or more) tables by looking at the foreign key of referring table.

A simple rule is, if the foreign key is a primary key itself in its own table, the relationship is probably 1 to 1, whereas if the foreign key is not a primary key in its own table, the relationship is probably 1 to many, where the table having the foreign key at the "many" end.

In your example, for departmentID in Employee, it is not a primary key. Therefore, in this situation, a Department can be referenced by a lot of Employees at the same time, hence the "1 to many" relation can be established.

However, in your quoted example [from mkyong.com](https://www.mkyong.com/mysql/how-to-define-one-to-one-relationship-in-mysql/), both tables (stock and stock_detail) use stock_id as primary key. In this situation, the "1 to 1" relation can be established.

Consider this: Both stock and stock_detail tables will only contain ONE single record having a certain value as stock_id. [I made a sample here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q680H.jpg).

Comment: Is it true to say that in the example from mkyong.com, the foreign key could have been defined in either table without much impact? What about in the above example... would it really matter if I made `Department` define the foreign key to the `Employee` table instead... I mean as long as the attributes of the key (primary key or not) remained the same at both ends?

Comment: You must define foreign key relationship from Employee (Employee.departmentID to Department.ID). It's simple, how are you going to establish a relation from Department to Employee? Employee's primary key is ID, but you can't refer Department's ID to Employee's ID, right?

If you are referring to a non-Primary-key field, the relation seems pointless to me at least.

Comment: I get it. So basically a foreign key must reference a unique key, whether it is primary or not. In the case above, `departmentId` column within `Employee` table is not unique... so it can't be referenced by the `id` in the `Department table. Is that true?

Comment: I tried and actually we can establish such a relation. But what is the point? So yea, I think it's sensible to only refer to primary/unique keys.

Answer (score 1):

This line here: `departmentId TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
        COMMENT "CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (departmentId) REFERENCES Department(id)"` refers to the Department table's `id` field. In `Department` you can have only once instance of each department, but in `Employee`, many employees might be in the same department, so that's a one to many from `Department -> Employee`

Does that make sense? Also, if you were to change the name of the department itself, there would be no need to update anything from the `Employee` table since it references back to the `Deparment` table automatically.

Comment: Okay, but in that case I don't understand why the following link is describing a 1-to-1 relationship. Since `stock_detail` is defining a foreign key constraint to `stock`... doesn't that make it a 1-to-many relationship from `stock -> stock_detail`?

https://www.mkyong.com/mysql/how-to-define-one-to-one-relationship-in-mysql/ 

Why is the link a 1-1 but my example 1-Many?

Comment: In the link you provided, the id from the left table is also the primary key in the right table. That means that only one id in the left table can exist in the right table also. It's pretty rare that you would use a 1 to 1 relationship though. If you think you need it, stop and examine your data structure very carefully to see if that's really the best solution and maybe consult someone else. It **MIGHT** be the right solution, but you'd better be certain or it will come back to bite you later.

Comment: Since then a column [`COMMENT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html#idm139834247609232) is used to define a constraint? It is just a comment, not a constraint, not a link to other table, nothing. Just a blob of ignored text, from the server's point of view. Read about the syntax of the [`CREATE TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) statement.

Comment: @Difster Aaah! Okay. I think the penny has just dropped. So if both keys are primary (or unique) keys then it is a 1-to-1. If the left key is unique and the right key not unique then it is a 1-to-many. But if the left key is not unique and the right key is unique then it is many-to-1. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. But you also have to be careful of 1 to many and many-to-many, they can cause you trouble if you're not careful also.

Comment: @axiac You are right in principle, but `comment` is actually read by the yii framework and used to define relationships.

Comment: @Difster What do you mean by "if you're not careful"? Any examples?

Comment: I just mean that if you use many-to-many or many-to-one, be sure to have a very good reason for it. There are actually lots of times when you have many to many but that's usually an intermediary table used to store two foreign keys from two different tables to form one unique key when they're combined. But I think you're new to database structures so you might want to go do some reading on that, there's not enough space here to get in to it throughly.

Comment: @Difster That's fine. But would you mind explaining whether defining the foreign key in either side makes a difference? Or is it only the uniqueness of the id that defines 1 or many? So for instance, in a one to one relationship.... it doesn't matter whether the left table contains the foreign key or the right table? Is that correct? And in the case above, what if I was to define the foreign key in the `Department` table?

Comment: Let's say you are assigning students to seats in various periods for a particular classroom (just one classroom for simplicity sake). Only one student can occupy one seat per period (which seat doesn't matter). So you have a table of periods and it has a primary key. Then you have a table of students which also has a primary key. Then you can have an intermediary table which stores the primary key from each of those tables and those two id's together make a unique key. Using two fields as a primary key is called a "compound key." Does that make sense?